# Bad font rendering Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, fonts

I was using ubuntu 16.04 and updated to 17.04, had the same issue in both versions and been trying to solve it for a long time now. The issue is with font rendering mostly in websites (in all browsers) the font shows as if it was too small or bad rendered like the following screenshot (the top menu text for example):
[image]

It is worse than the screenshot don't know why it looks better in the screenshot

I'm using Nvidia GTX 970 gpu and nvidia 384.90 driver from graphics-drivers ppa

What could be the issue?